# How to customize form django with fields of the diferents Models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I need to display a field on a form and another field on a Model in html page.

```
class CatracaForm(forms.Form):
    ra = forms.CharField(label='RA', max_length=30)


class MotivoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Motivo
        fields = ['descrmotivo', 'obs']
```

In my HTML page I want show ra and descrmotivo field.
The descrmotivo field  should be a combobox component.

How to make this?

Answer (score 0):

```
# if you want to show 'ra' and 'descrmotivo', then you can define a custom field in the same class.

class MotivoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ra = forms.CharField(label='RA', max_length=30)
    class Meta:
        model = Motivo
        fields = ['descrmotivo', 'ra']


# If you want to show combobox for 'descrmotivo' field, then you can use 'choices' option in your model, For example

models.py

PROGRESS_STATUS = (
    ('Assigned','Assigned'),
    ('In Progress','In Progress'),
    ('Completed','Completed'),
)

class Motivo(models.Model):
    descrmotivo = models.CharField(choices=PROGRESS_STATUS, max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.descrmotivo


# this will show a combobox which will have an option of 'Assigned', 'In Progress', 'Completed'
```